# Can't properly add .dll reference in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, dll, shell32

I'm trying to add and use shell32.dll to my console project in VS Code. I put it to root folder of project, ..\bin and ..\bin\Debug. I made `dotnet restore`. Code in my .csproj file is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Shell32">
      <HintPath>shell32.dll</HintPath>
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

But when I add `using Shell32;` to Program.cs it is giving error "The type or namespace name 'Shell32' could not be found". Please advise what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You the COM reference to add `Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation` instead of referencing the actuall Shell32.dll.

Sample XML:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="Shell32.dll">
      <Guid>50a7e9b0-70ef-11d1-b75a-00a0c90564fe</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: And how can I reference it in VS Code? I find only how to add reference in Visual Studio.

Comment: Copy paste the XML I posted instead of <Reference Include="Shell32">.

Comment: I did that, and still getting error "The type or namespace name 'Shell32' could not be found when trying to use it.

Comment: Ok. I ended using WindowsAPICodePack to get my task with shell done.